# How to write to different output file from given condition in template toolkit

Tags: perl, templates, template-toolkit

I am working on Template Toolkit with perl language. I am reading a YAML file in perl and i want to write to different output file based on yaml value using template toolkit. Could you please help me on this

YAML file: test.yaml

```
---
constraints:
  data1:
    file: file1
    value: 'Writing in file 1: DATA1'
  data2:
    file: file2
    value: 'Writing in file 2: DATA2'
  data3:
    file: file1
    value: 'Writing in file 1: DATA3'
```

Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Template;
use YAML qw(LoadFile); 
use Data::Dumper;

my $tt = Template->new({
INCLUDE_PATH => './',
INTERPOLATE  => 1,
}) or die "$Template::ERROR\n";

my %data = % {LoadFile('test.yaml') };
my $report;
$tt->process('test.tt', \%data, \$report) or die $tt->error(), "\n";
 print $report;
```

`test.tt`: Not finished, only started:

```
[% FOREACH a IN constraints.keys.sort %]
[% IF constraints.$a.file == 'file1' %]
constraints.$a.value > file1  --------**Need help on this**
[% ELSE %]
constraints.$a.value > file2  --------**Need help on this**
[% END %]
[% END %]
```

Expected output:

```
file1:
Writing in file 1: DATA1
Writing in file 1: DATA3

file2:
Writing in file 2: DATA2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it outside the template.

```perl
use FindBin  qw( $RealBin );
use Template qw( );
use YAML     qw( LoadFile );

my $data = LoadFile( 'test.yaml' );

my $tt = Template->new({
   INCLUDE_PATH => $RealBin,
   INTERPOLATE  => 1,
});

for my $constraint_id ( sort keys $data->{ constraints }->%* ) {
   my $constraint = $data->{ constraints }{ $constraint_id };

   my $fn = $constraint->{ file };
   my $qfn = "$RealBin/$fn";
   open( my $fh, ">>", $qfn )
      or die( "Can't create `$qfn` or open for append: $!\n");

   my %vars = (
      value => $constraint->{ value },
   );

   $tt->process( 'test.tt', \%vars, $fh )
      or die( $tt->error(), "\n" );
}
```

```
[% value %]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose the output file from within a template.

The template should render (format) the input in a human-readable way. What you're trying to do should be in the Perl script.

```
use File::Slurp;
[...]
# Loop over all constraints
for my $constraint (keys %{$data{constraints}}) {
  # Render each constraint value to the specified file
  my $rendered_file_content;
  $tt->process(
    'render_constraint.tt',
    $data{constraints}->{$constraint}->{value},
    \$rendered_file_content,
  );
  write_file(
    $data{constraints}->{$constraint}->{file},
    $rendered_file_content,
  );
}
```

Notice:

1. You should read about [references in Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref). `%data = % {LoadFile('test.yaml') }` is usually not needed.
2. Names like `constraints`, `data`, `value` should be replaced by speaking ones. These names might be just placeholder examples for this question. Use `$car_brand` instead of `$value` in the real script (for example).
3. The concept looks risky from a security point of view. Ensure the file name never originates from web requests.